# Google Earth Engine - Reprojecting Vector FeatureCollections

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

I am calculating zonal statistics in Google Earth Engine, using an uploaded shapefile(EPSG:4326) and raster dataset (GHSL - EPSG:54009), so I need to reproject one of the layers.

Whilst I have reprojected the raster dataset to the EPSG:4326 and this solves the problem, I still would like to know how to reproject the vector layer to EPSG:54009 for future calculations.

I have tried several solutions, one of which results in an error of:`Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined`.

Please can someone update my script?

```
// Define an arbitrary region in which to compute random points.
var region = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-119.224, 34.669, -99.536, 50.064);

// Create 1000 random points in the region.
var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(region);

// Display the points.
Map.centerObject(randomPoints);
Map.addLayer(randomPoints, {}, 'random points');


// Define mollweide projection as wkt
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';


// Define wkt as projection
var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);


// Apply transformation
var points_moll = ee.randomPoints.transform(proj_mollweide, 0.001);

print(points_moll);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if transforming vector is worth it, but here's the trick.

According to docs, `.transform()` is ony applied to an `ee.Feature`, not `ee.FeatureCollection`. So you have to map the procedure over a FeatureCollection.

```
// Define an arbitrary region in which to compute random points.
var region = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-119.224, 34.669, -99.536, 50.064);

// Create 1000 random points in the region.
var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(region);

// Display the points.
Map.centerObject(randomPoints);
Map.addLayer(randomPoints, {}, 'random points');


var dst_projection = 'EPSG:3857';


// Apply transformation
var transformer = function(a_feature) {
  var transformed_feature = a_feature.transform(dst_projection, 0.001);
  return transformed_feature;
};

var points_prj = randomPoints.map(transformer);

print(points_prj);
```

This is [a link to the snippet on EE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6c42cc48b56a1d026430d0fec6b34c0b)

Comment: Hi, I also tried a transformer like the above too with no errors but If you look at the actual coordinates of output, they are still in WSG84. I also exported the point coordinates into GIS to spot check this.

Comment: Why do you want to transform vector? I'm pretty sure it is done in a background when it is involved with a raster having a different projection

Comment: Firstly, say if you have a single vector file in one projection and several rasters in another (same) projection, then surely it makes sense to reproject just the single vector. Moreover, for some calculations, it's more intuitive to work in metres than degrees (e.g. WSG84). Finally, I would like to know how to do this for future reference when working with GEE. I've also tested running zonal stats with a vector file in one projection and a raster in another, the results are 0 (as you would expect).

Comment: I think you should check out [this manual](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections). `Earth Engine is designed so that you rarely have to worry about map projections when doing computations. As with scale, the projection in which computations take place is determined on a "pull" basis. Specifically, inputs are requested in the output projection.`

Comment: @tastatham I figured out the problem. The function I suggested works correctly, you can check it by specifying projection in EPSG notation, i.e. `var transformed_feature = a_feature.transform('EPSG:3857', 0.001)'`. So the problem is in the way you define your projection or the projection itself. But it is a different question to be asked separately. Please don't forget to accept the answer to this one.

Comment: @basille thanks for your help. Yes, that works ok. I've had problems defining the Mollweide projection in various projects in the past, EPSG codes are more tight. I replicated your script by reprojecting points over England to British National Grid.  https://code.earthengine.google.com/edf3740496faabe551f888df7e4c71f6